# useEffect cleanup function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I get this warning 'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.'

> Code

```
 const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
 fetch('/mypost', {
  headers: {
    cookie: 'access_token',
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    setPhoto(data.mypost);
  });
}, []);
```

The data is fetched but I could'nt figure what to add in the clean up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

The problem is that the fetch request resolves but the component has unmounted (*for some reason*) and so the state update can't occur now.

## Solution

You need to use an [Abort Controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) to cancel in-flight requests. If the component unmounts, an effect cleanup function cancels the fetch request.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController(); // <-- create controller
  const { signal } = controller; // <-- get signal for request

  fetch('/mypost', {
    headers: {
      cookie: 'access_token',
    },
    signal, // <-- pass signal with options
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPhoto(data.mypost);
    });

  return () => controller.abort(); // <-- return cleanup function to abort
}, []);
```

> **Note:** When `abort()` is called, the `fetch()` promise rejects with an
> `AbortError`.

You will likely need to catch this promise rejection somewhere. You can append a `.catch` block to the Promise chain.

```
  fetch('/mypost', {
    headers: {
      cookie: 'access_token',
    },
    signal, // <-- pass signal with options
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      setPhoto(data.mypost);
    })
    // catch any rejected fetch promises (including aborted fetches!)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This is a partial solution as the abort controller only rejects the first fetch promise. If unmounting is called after it completes, but before the last promise chain completed, `setPhoto` will be called when the component is already unmounted.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
let isMounted = true;
 fetch('/mypost', {
  headers: {
    cookie: 'access_token',
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    if (isMounted)  setPhoto(data.mypost);
  });

//cleanup function
return () => { isMounted = false };
    
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Generic JSON fetch demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-murdock-wxq8u?file=/src/TestComponent.js)

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { useAsyncEffect } from "use-async-effect2";
import cpFetch from "cp-fetch";

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);

  useAsyncEffect(
    function* () {
      const response = yield cpFetch('/mypost');
      setPhoto((yield response.json()).mypost);
    },
    []
  );

  return <div></div>;
}
```