# React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, amazon-cognito, use-effect

I am practicing AWS' Cognito. For front-end I am using React and for routing I am using React-router-dom. For Cognito validation I am using [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) package. My Congito `signin`, `signup` and `confirmation` logic works fine. I made one helper function where I validate the Congnito. and reuse it in different component. I split my Nav bar into two components. From Congnito current user I made one callback function and use it in useEffect, and dependencies put the callback function, by default `getAuthenticatedUser` is null. I add condition where it fetch the data, if  `getAuthenticatedUser` then redirect to `signin` and `signup` page. Because of this condition I am getting the error: `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.....`. Also when I signed in it does not change the nav bar name, I have to refresh the browser then I can see the change. I share my code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cognito-wpe3e?file=/src/App.tsx).

**This is my helper function**

```
    import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const Pool_Data = {
  UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_IEyFfUupx',
  ClientId: '63fc9g5c3g9vhqdalrv9eqhoa2',
};

export default function useHandler() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    loading: false,
    isAuthenticated: false
  })

  const { loading, isAuthenticated } = state;

  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(Pool_Data)

  const getAuthenticatedUser = useCallback(() => {
    return userPool.getCurrentUser();
  },
    [],
  );

  console.log(getAuthenticatedUser());


  useEffect(() => {
    getAuthenticatedUser()
  }, [getAuthenticatedUser])

  const signOut = () => {
    return userPool.getCurrentUser()?.signOut()
  }
  console.log(getAuthenticatedUser());

  return {
    loading,
    isAuthenticated,
    userPool,
    getAuthenticatedUser,
    signOut
  }
};
```

**This is my navigation**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import SigninLinks from './SigninLinks';
import SignoutLinks from './SignoutLinks';
import useHandlder from '../configHandler/useHandler';


const Nav = () => {
  const { getAuthenticatedUser } = useHandlder();


  const Links = getAuthenticatedUser() ? <SigninLinks /> : <SignoutLinks />
  return (
    <nav className="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="brand-logo">Logo</h2>
        {
          Links
        }

      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

**This is Home screen where it display the data and getting error**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { api } from './api';
import useHandlder from './configHandler/useHandler'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState([]);
  const { getAuthenticatedUser } = useHandlder();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setstate(data)
  }

  return getAuthenticatedUser() === null ? <Redirect to="/signin" /> : //In here is the //error happening.
    <div className="row">
      <h1>hello welcome to home</h1>
      {
        state?.map((i: string, id: number) => <h1 key={id}>{i.title}</h1>)
      }
    </div>

};

export default Home;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529046/8690857 In your case you start out on the home path (`"/"`) and the fetch is made when `Home` mounts, but then the `Redirect` pushes a new route and `Home` unmounts.

Comment: Hmmm. what should I do in my case of code?

Comment: Follow my solution and in the effect callback create an abort controller and signal to send with the `fetch` GET request and return a cleanup function to abort any unsettled promises if `Home` unmounts early. If the other answer isn't quite clear enough I can answer here if you like.

Comment: I did not get it .

Comment: I made username: test12 and password: Helloworld1!.

Comment: Also would please tell why, nav redirect to the home after signin but  it  still display the `signin` and `signup` nav. I need to refresh the browser in oder to see home nav bar. Same happen to logout button. I press logout button but it still shows the home nav bar menus.

Comment: Seems you have several issues you are asking about. Try narrow the focus of your question to *a* specific issue. Which would you like tackled first?

Comment: first one :D unmount component.

Comment: @DrewReese I am still waiting for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is your app starts on the home (`"/"`) path and renders the `Home` component. `Home` initiates a GET request upon mounting and checks for an authenticated user, and if there is none, renders a redirect to your "/signin" route.

The `fetch` is *asynchronous* so when the redirect occurs the GET request is resolving *after* `Home` has been unmounted and it tries to update the local state with the response data, but can't.

## Solution

You need to use an [Abort Controller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort) to cancel in-flight requests. If the component unmounts, an effect cleanup function cancels the fetch request. In `Home` update the `useEffect` hook to create an `AbortController` and `signal` to be used in a cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController(); // <-- create controller
  const { signal } = controller; // <-- get signal for request

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,
      { signal } // <-- pass signal with options
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setstate(data);
  };

  fetchData();

  return () => controller.abort(); // <-- return cleanup function to abort
}, []);
```

## Demo

[image: Edit Cognito (forked)]

Comment: I got this error now: `index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.`

Comment: @krisna I added a link to a running codesandbox I tested this in. I also occasionally (1 out of 5 times maybe?) see that error but I think it's unrelated to this issue. Reloading the page seems to resolve it for now. Notice now in the console you no longer receive the warning about attempting to update state of an unmounted component.